# how to create action cable connection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags "ActionCable","User #{current_user.id}"
    end

    def find_varified_user
      if current_user = env['wardon'].user
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is an excellent looking middle part of a file

Comment: but action cable didn't established connection

Comment: And your question is? You need to be specific. What exactly did you try? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? "It didn't work" tells us nothing.

Comment: What is your question bro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you generate a channel

```
rails g channel {channel_name} {the action you will send to}
```

this will generate the channel in "app/channels" folder

then mount the channel in routes.rb

```
  #config/routes.rb
     # add this line
   mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

then you subscribe to the channel from your client app and use the method you've created in your channel

you can review this tutorial 
[Create Chat Using Action Cable](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/creating-a-chat-using-rails-action-cable)

but ignore the client-side part